# Why is my React State not updating in this functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I created a simple functional component to show my issue, so this is the file:

```
export default function DataCentreSummaryPage() {
    const [hello, setHello ] = useState(false)

    const checkHello = () => {
        if([1,2,3].includes(1)){
            setHello(true)
        } 
      }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        checkHello()
    }, []);
  
    return (
      
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

I initially set hello to have a state of false. However, in my useEffect hook it should update the state to true via the checkHello() function. Even if I change the code and do it like this where the function is created and called inside of the useEffect hook, it still does not update the state

```
export default function DataCentreSummaryPage() {
    const [hello, setHello ] = useState(false)

   
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkHello = () => {
            if([1,2,3].includes(1)){
                setHello(true)
            } 
          }
        checkHello()
    }, []);
  
    return (
      
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Can someone pls help me understand this pls and help me find a potential solution

Comment: How are you determining that the state is not being updated? Doesn't seem like you're logging or rendering the state value.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wjvdvt?file=src%2FApp.js), the state does update. Assuming that the condition inside the if-statement is just for this example, maybe the condition in your project isn't working as expected?